# Swift - Can I read the value of a enum as an optional without doing a switch?

Tags: swift, enums

Does Swift have a syntax similar to `case .enumCase(let value) = enum` that can be used as a one liner to read the enum as a specific case, or a `nil`

For instance with a `Swift.Result` instead of

```
let error: Error?
if case let .failure(value) = result {
  error = value
} else {
  error = nil
}
```

can I write something as

```
case let .failure(error) = result // Well this I can't
let error = result.as(.failure)
```

Comment: Pattern matching inside an `if`, `guard` or `switch` is the only way to access enum associated values. But you can put them inside a computed property on the enum, so you don't have to repeat them.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify working with `Result` (or other enums) you can use next extension:

```swift
extension Result {
    var value: Success? {
        if case let .success(value) = self {
            return value
        }
        return nil
    }

    var error: Failure? {
        if case let .failure(error) = self {
            return error
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Then you can get optional values in single line:

```swift
let value = result.value
let error = result.error

if let value = result.value {
    print(value)
}

if let error = result.error {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Yeah so for each enum you do have to write the extension :( thanks for confirming